# Laptop keyboard and trackpad disabled after driver mishap in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, grub2, keyboard, touchpad

I managed to mess up the drivers for my laptop keyboard and trackpad last night, and so I can't type anything to restore the original drivers.

Plugging in a USB keyboard or mouse doesn't work either.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have 18.04 on a USB stick. I can boot into 18.04 and the keyboard and trackpad work through that, but I don't know how to restore the drivers for 16.04 or edit /etc/default/grub to boot into terminal to fix it. Every solution I'm finding involves typing.

Can I edit the 16.04 /etc/default/grub from 18.04?

Is there a key combo I can hold before Ubuntu 16.04 loads to force it to load into Terminal? The keyboard works until 16.04 loads.

Comment: Try holding Shift or Esc on startup to enter grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

How are the keyboard and trackpad connected to the PC?  If it's USB, there are problematic handoff settings in your BIOS most likely.

Comment: It's a laptop. It's definitely a driver issue, I'm just lost how to get the generic drivers back.

Comment: Well, that's the fun part.  If you can't use a keyboard or mouse, then using modprobe won't help.  But that would be the tool to utilize.  If bad comes to worse, you would need to compile the kernel yourself to include the modules/drivers that run your keyboard and mouse.  But yeah, if the USB isn't working and your keyboard and mouse isn't working, you have nothing to lose by double-checking your USB handoff/emulation in your bios settings.  Different versions of Ubuntu have different quirks that don't get fixed.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72625/why-is-usb-not-working-in-linux-when-it-works-in-uefi-bios

Comment: I was able to edit /etc/default/grub and boot into console and from there I removed the incorrect driver and restored the xorg drivers.